# Move Expresso Store's promotions back to the channel entries

Tags: expresso-store

I've updated from Store 1.6 to 2.3. My client is very unhappy with how the "sale price" has moved from the rest of the store information. It is in it's own "promotions" tab now, which makes sense but unfortunately I have to change it.

Has anyone tried moving the "discount sales" back into the channel entries? I've been screwing around to try and pull in the data but I'm having no luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any off the shelf ways to do it.

It would be possible to build a separate fieldtype which displays and updates sales related to a particular product. You could then add this to the product channels where you need it. However, I don't think there is anything like this which has been released yet.